# Eurowings Basic - Hand Luggage Allowance

Tags: air-travel, legal, hand-luggage, eurowings

The web-site says the following about hand luggage:

> Each passenger may carry one item of hand luggage on board with a maximum weight of 8 kg and maximum dimensions of 55 x 40 x 23 cm. This excludes foldable garment bags carried as hand luggage, which may measure up to 57 x 54 x 15 cm.
>
> Due to the limited space available in the cabin, larger or heavier pieces of luggage must be checked in at the airport counter and will be carried in the hold. This is not only for your own safety and the safety of your fellow passengers, but also for your comfort.

now I have two questions:

1) what is meant exactly with second paragraph? I mean, I don't know beforehand if they have limited space for the particular flight, so when and who decides if my hand luggage goes in hold?

2) is there also included additional small bag for laptop, camera etc. (Like Ryanair does), even though it says **ONE item** of hand luggage, I want to make sure. I could not find any info about that.

p.s. I am talking about **BASIC FARE**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second paragraph is saying that any luggage that is heavier than 8kg or bigger than the maximum dimensions will be checked in, and you will be charged for it. This is regardless of whether there is or isn't space in the flight to accomodate it. In other words, **if your bag doesn't respect the rules, it will be checked-in.**

I think the regulation you quoted is as explicit as it gets. You are allowed **one piece of hand luggage** with a maximum weight of 8kg and dimensions of 55 x 40 x 23 cm. One piece means that you can't carry an extra small bag for your laptop/camera/beauti-case/etc.

Comment: There is also the possibility that hand luggage, which is according to the rules, has to be checked in, because there is simply not enough space. However this is usually done at the gate, and you don't have to pay for it. I encountered this twice on a fully booked Lufthansa flight.

Comment: I think the comment of @dunni is a valid different interpretation of that rule, similar as with Ryanair. I checked the German wording of that paragraph and it is not any clearer.

Comment: @mts Yes definitely however the paragraph only mentions `larger or heavier pieces of luggage`.

Comment: I know, it could be as in "relatively large" or "larger than the limit". Can't offer any insight either :(

Comment: I was just referring to gate checking hand luggage, which presumably seems to happen quite often in the US with the regional airlines. The second paragraph in the OP refers to luggage which exceeds the limitations, IMHO (because it says "must be checked"), which would then be counted against your checked luggage allowance, whereas gate checked hand luggage (which is inside the limits), doesn't count.

Comment: The sentence "Due to the limited space available in the cabin" could however be a bit misleading, but for me it just sounds like the reason, why checked luggage exists in the first place (and which sounds quite reasonable), and is not referring to any specific limits of airplane sizes or hand luggage capacities.